# How to install Docker onto a jenkins machine (through gui only)

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

How do i install Docker onto a jenkins machine?
This machine is hosted on the cloud and hence I don't have access to the command line.

I've tried the web and there isn't any helpful guides in order to do this, the cloud bees requires on an agent to have docker installed.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Is it not possible to ssh into the machine? If that's the case I would recommend you to look at alternative hosting solutions as you might run into trouble later on.

Answer (score 0):

You can have docker available as tool for builds ( and therefore you can build and start any container using a (pipeline) job) .

You go to: manage jenkins > global tool configuration > docker installations > add docker

[image: docker latest installed]

Then , in your pipeline you use the "tools section" to make it available to your build. Here is an example

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        label 'yourDockerAgentLabel'
    }
    environment {
        SOME_ENV_VAR = 'some_value'
    }
    tools {
        docker 'latest'
        jdk 'your_jdk_version'
    }
    stages {
        stage('first stage') {
          sh("docker build .")
       }
    }
```

}